# National Weather Service (NWS) Valid Time Event Code (VTEC) Parser Regular Expression (Regex)

Tags: regex

The National Weather Service (NWS) embeds machine readable components in its text bulletins and syndicated format feeds, called Valid Time Event Code (VTEC).

More information on VTEC http://www.nws.noaa.gov/os/vtec/ 
Example of Text Bulletins: http://www.nws.noaa.gov/view/national.php?prodtype=allwarnings

I am developing a parser to interpret a sequence of VTECs embedded within an NWS bulletin and have a regular expression to capture the logic, that I am happy to share, see below, but not 100% sure if I am doing this right.

Specifically,
1.  Is there any specification on how many VTECs may be embedded in any one NWS message (or its update)? Usually seeing just one, but if there are multiple, what is the hierarchy, if any - does the last one cancel the previous? Or, do all the VTECs have the same weight?
2.  If a Hydrological or H-VTEC is issued, is it always immediately following a P-VTEC?  
3.  Is there a "parent-child"  relationship, in the XML document sense, between an H-VTEC element and P-VTEC element?  
4.  Can the VTEC be used as a unique identifier for a message or its update?  If not, what would be the "primary key" in the database sense?  Could perhaps a hash of the VTEC along with bulletin update date be used?  Or is any other combination of fields recommended?

The following regular expression is able to pick up the VTEC, assuming any number of P-VTECs may be released and if there is an H-VTEC it will always be preceded by a "parent" P-VTEC.

```
[/][OTEX][.](NEW|CON|EXT|EXA|EXB|UPG|CAN|EXP|COR|ROU)[.][\w]{4}[.][A-Z][A-Z][.][WAYSFON][.][0-9]{4}[.][0-9]{6}[T][0-9]{4}[Z][-][0-9]{6}[T][0-9]{4}[Z][/]([^/]*[/][\w]{5}[.][[N0-3U]][.][A-Z][A-Z][.][0-9]{6}[T][0-9]{4}[Z][.][0-9]{6}[T][0-9]{4}[Z][.][0-9]{6}[T][0-9]{4}[Z][.](NO|NR|UU|OO)[/])?
```

Comment: NWS Syndicated Feed Example: http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/us.php?x=0

Comment: VTEC Explanation (one-pager): http://weather.gov/os/vtec/pdfs/VTEC_explanation6.pdf

Comment: Regex Validator: http://myregexp.com/signedJar.html

Comment: While it appears that you have done quite a bit of research and put plenty of effort into solving your problem, I believe only somebody well-versed in the area of the NWS and their VTECs will be able to answer any of your questions. They aren't really programming questions, and you may be better off seeking advice from an outlet that is more-versed in this area.

Comment: Have already posted to nws.answers@noaa.gov.  I usually find all answers here - so next person coding VTEC may find this useful.

Comment: More on the regex:  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B01JiMtrxBDmR1NoeExjUHJBVW8/

Comment: I almost threw up reading that regex.  I realize you aren't the one who made it, but it hurts my eyes seeing digit character classes instead of `\d`, and single-character character classes, as well as that nested character class, which would function incorrectly even by their description.  The `[[N0-3U]]` will either break, or match the letters N, U, and a range from Zero to Three and also square brackets, or will simply behave the same as `[0-3NU]`.  As well as other things.  It's just ugly.

Comment: `/[OTEX]\.(NEW|CON|EXT|EXA|EXB|UPG|CAN|EXP|COR|ROU)\.\w{4}\.[A-Z]{2}\.[WAYSFON]\.\d{4}\.\d{6}T\d{4}Z-\d{6}T\d{4}Z/([^/]*/\w{5}\.[NU0-3]\.[A-Z]{2}\.\d{6}T\d{4}Z\.\d{6}T\d{4}Z\.\d{6}T\d{4}Z\.(NO|NR|UU|OO)/)?`

Comment: Thanks, Suamere.  The regex has been tested, updated in the Google Doc above with due credit to you.

Answer (score 0):

The VTEC is described in more detail at: http://www.nws.noaa.gov/directives/sym/pd01017003curr.pdf

In case the link expires, this may be found also by drilling down as follows:

1. NWS directives.  http://www.nws.noaa.gov/directives/
2. (Click on) Operations and Services.
3. (Scroll Down) Dissemination.

After reading the document, answers to #2 and #3 are a resounding YES.  H-VTEC will always be supplemental to an immediately preceding P-VTEC.  Regarding #1, multiple P-VTECs are possible and the logic is probably more complex than regex can weed out.  Regarding #4, the answer is almost certainly NO, mainly because VTEC could be missing in an NWS bulletin, so does not classify as a primary key.

So the regex needed to parse out a VTEC string, thanks to Suamere, is most likely:

```
/[OTEX]\.(NEW|CON|EXT|EXA|EXB|UPG|CAN|EXP|COR|ROU)\.\w{4}\.[A-Z]{2}\.[WAYSFON]\.\d{4}\.\d{6}T\d{4}Z-\d{6}T\d{4}Z/([^/]*/\w{5}\.[N0-3U]\.[A-Z]{2}\.\d{6}T\d{4}Z\.\d{6}T\d{4}Z\.\d{6}T\d{4}Z\.(NO|NR|UU|OO)/)?
```